# Make a short if statement

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin

In my code I have this if statement:

```
if (categoryName == "SomeName1" || categoryName == "SomeName2" || 
    categoryName == "SomeName3" || categoryName == "SomeName4" || 
    categoryName == "SomeName5" || categoryName == "SomeName6") {
    // Do something
}
```

I was wondering if I could shorten this if. Something like:

```
if (categoryName == "SomeName1" and "SomeName2" and "SomeName3" ...) {
    // Do something
}
```

Is there any aproach to do something like this in Kotlin?

Comment: use some "list"/"set" and contains?

Comment: Store everything in an array and check the array

Comment: FWIW: Just because it "can" be done in a "slightly shorter one-line" doesn't mean it ought to be.. clean code in many case is actually the result of breaking up such "one lines", especially when such increases self-documentation clarity and overall maintainability.

Comment: As written in comments to answers, I'd recommend considering `if (knownCategory(categoryName)) ..`. Then there can be an if/switch/list-contains etc inside the method and not have to "worry". This makes the original line shorter and arguably increases the clarity/self-documentation and maintainability (eg. adding a new category or changing how the category is classified).

Comment: I'd argue `categoryName in listOf("SomeName1", "SomeName2", ...)` is short and clear. It works for Python at least. Too long a list can still make that suitable for a separate list variable, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quick and dirty**

```
if (Arrays.asList("SomeName1", "SomeName2", "SomeName3", 
                  "SomeName4", "SomeName5", "SomeName6")
          .contains(categoryName)) {
    // Do something
}
```

**Better**

```
val myList = Arrays.asList("SomeName1", "SomeName2", "SomeName3", 
                           "SomeName4", "SomeName5", "SomeName6");
if (myList.contains(categoryName)) {
    // Do something
}
```

**EDIT**
Voddan's answer using `setOf` is better.

Comment: I would pull the asList to a variable/field: `if (knownCategories.contains(categoryName)) ..` it really does not add much benefit if left inline. Could get about the same effect with a shorter variable name. And in both cases could just pull the condition into a method: `if (knownCategory(categoryName)) ..`

Comment: He wants short so I give a one-liner :) Could even use IntStream and anyMatch if there are more than 6 elements with all the same pattern.

Comment: Not very Kotlin-specific, is it?

Comment: Ho I did not see the Kotlin tag, assumed it was java as the syntax is the same. I guess I will remove the java8 example then.

Comment: Downvoted because this is Java code, and not Kotlin code. I know they interop, but I do not think this is the best answer. See voddan's answer, using `setOf` and `in` operator. That is Kotlin.

Comment: I commented already on his answer and said it was probably better.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `when` statement. The syntax kind of looks like what you were asking for:

```
when (categoryName) {
    "SomeName1", "SomeName2",  "SomeName3", "SomeName4", "SomeName5", "SomeName6" -> // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a switch statement?

```
switch(categoryName) {
    case "SomeName1":
    case "SomeName2":
    case "SomeName3":
    case "SomeName4":
    case "SomeName5":
    case "SomeName6":
        // Do something
        break;
    default: 
        // Do something else
        break;
}
```

Comment: I would consider using a `switch` *inside* a method. Then it's easy to abstract: `if (knownCategory(categoryName)) ..` where the switch/return sequence is entirely in knownCategory method.

Comment: Question is for Kotlin , so it should be `when` expression not `switch` statement.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using a regular expression:

```
if (categoryName.matches(Regex("SomeName[1-6]"))) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most Kotlin-ish solution IMO:

```
val names = setOf("SomeName1", "SomeName2", "SomeName3", "SomeName4", "SomeName5", "SomeName6")

if (categoryName in names) {
    // Do something
}
```

It utilizes searching in a hash set, so it may also be the fastest solution under certain conditions.

Comment: I think this is better than my solution.